# Mixed content issue in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, https

I have a following form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/admin/email') }}">
```

On localhost, it generates `https//....` but on server it generates `http://...` which results in mixed content warning. Is there any flag to fix it ?

Comment: On the server what `url` did you set in the `.env` file?

Comment: No url set in env

Comment: Sorry, I meant `APP_PATH`

Comment: Laravel uses the schema from the current url, are you on a https url? Are you using Cloudflare by any chance?

Comment: Recurrent problem when your app is behind a load-balancer or a proxy.
Have a look at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/mixed-content-issue-content-must-be-served-as-https

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/admin/email') }}">
```

actualy `url()` accepts three params. `string`,`Array`,`bool` the third params is for secure, means https. you can set it to true.

i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you look at declaration of `url` method, it's like this

`function url($path = null, $parameters = [], $secure = null)`

so third parameter is for generating secure URL or not, so your line will be like this

`<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/admin/email', [], true) }}">`